# Batch processing with spark and azure

Tags: azure, apache-spark, bigdata

I am working for an energy provider company. Currently, we are generating 1 GB data in form of flat files per day. We have decided to use azure data lake store to store our data, in which we want to do batch processing on a daily basis. My question is that what is the best way to transfer the flat files into azure data lake store? and after the data is pushed into azure I am wondering whether it is good idea to process the data with HDInsight  spark? like Dataframe API or SparkSQL and finally visualize it with azure?

Comment: Do you mean Azure Data **L**ake?

Comment: Using `AzCopy` to blob storage and then code to transform into Data Lake would be an option if Data lake doesn't provide something directly

Comment: Where is your source data stored? A database? Flat files?

Comment: Yes, it is currently flat files. Actually, there is ETL process that collects data from databases, ,transforms them and generates flat files in the end and then put it in local file system

Comment: [*Use the Azure Import/Export service for offline copy of data to Data Lake Store*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-offline-bulk-data-upload).

Comment: TBH each question here should be a separate question ([SO] is about detail not broad overview). And even then they are probably too board or asking for product recommendations (which is off topic).

Answer (score 1):

For a daily load from a local file system I would recommend using Azure Data Factory Version 2. You have to install  Integration Runtimes on Premise (more than one for High Avalibility). You have to consider several security topics (local firewalls, network connectivity etc.) A detailed documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations). There are also some good [Tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool) available. With Azure Data Factory you can trigger your upload to Azure with a [Get-Metadata-Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) and use e. g. an Azure Databricks Notebook Activity for further Spark processing.